# How to get the length of an object array object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to get the length of an object array object in angular.

Here's the code:

***list.component.ts***

```
const obj: any = {};
this.days.forEach((x: any) => {
  const itemFilter = this.rowData.filter((item: any) => item);
  itemFilter.forEach((item: any) => {
    const date = format(item.lastpmdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    if (format(x.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') === date) {
      if (obj[date]) {
        obj[date].push(item);
      } else {
        obj[date] = [item];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

What I need is to get the length of the object array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Object.keys(obj).length ?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I put the ```Object.keys(obj).length``` below the ```this.days.forEach((x: any) => { .... }});```.. it ```returns 3```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the keys of the target object with `Object.keys` and then check its length as a normal array:

```
Object.keys(this.days).length
```

If you have an object of arrays:

```
Object.values(this.days).map(v => v.length)
```

Object.values() allows to iterate over the object values instead of the keys.

Having these, you can then get the length for each of the inner arrays.

Comment: it ```return 7```, it should ```return 1, 1, 7```

Comment: ```1``` for ```date: 2019-11-24```, ```1``` for  ```date: 2019-11-25``` then ```7``` for ```date: 2019-11-30```

Comment: I updated the answer, and the new code returns what you need.